# Is there difference between support of function and support of module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $A$ be a commutative ring, and $M =A$ can be treated as an $A$-module. Let $f\in A$ we have the submodule $(f) \subset A$ therefore we can consider the support of the module $(f)$, which is :

$$\text{supp} ((f)) = \{p\in \text{Spec} A\mid (f)_p \ne 0\} \tag{1}$$

where $(f)_p$ means taking the localization of the module $(f)$ at $p$.

There is another definition of support since $f \in A = \mathcal{O}(\text{Spec} A)$ the support of function $f$ can also be defined as ：

$$\text{supp}(f) = \{p\in\text{Spec} A \mid f(p) \ne 0\} \tag{2}$$

Where $f(p)$ means the image of $f$ in the residue field via the canonical map $$A\to A_p\to A_p/(pA_p) = \kappa(p)$$

---

I am not sure, but I found these two different definitions of support are different, in the first one by this post in stack project [thereom 10.40.7](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07Z5) which shows if we use definition (1), we have

> **Lemma 10.40.7.** Let $A$ be a ring, let $M (= A)$ be an $A$-module, and let
> $f\in A$. Then $p\in V(\text{Ann}(f)) = \text{supp} ( (f))$ if and only if $f$ **does not map to**
> **zero** in $A_p$.

However in definition (2): $f(p) \ne 0$ iff $f$ **does not map into the maximal ideal** $pA_p$ in the local ring $A_p$.

You see one is equivalent to not mapping to zero another one is not mapped to the maximal ideal. Are these two definitions of support different?

Comment: Yes, they are different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes they are different, and I was also confused by this when I first noticed.

By Hartshorne Exercies II.2.16.(a) we actually have $\operatorname{supp}(f)=D(f)$, i.e. the set of primes not containing $f$. And by your Lemma we have $\operatorname{supp}((f))=V(\operatorname{Ann}(f))$. So the former is open, while the latter is closed. Also, it is clear from the definition that $D(f)\subseteq V(\operatorname{Ann}(f))$. It is then natural to ask if we always have $\overline{D(f)}=V(\operatorname{Ann}(f))$. But this may fail, for example if $A=k[\epsilon]=k[x]/(x^2)$ and $f=\epsilon$. It may even fail if $f$ is non-nilpotent: take $A=k[x,y]/(xy^2)$, denote by $\overline{x},\overline{y}$ the classes of $x,y$ in side $A$ and let $f=\overline{y}$. Then $\overline{D(f)}=V(\overline{x})$, while $\operatorname{Ann}(f)=(\overline{x}\overline{y})\subseteq \sqrt{(0)}$ and thus $V(\operatorname{Ann}(f))=\operatorname{Spec}A$.

What we can say in general is the following: define $\operatorname{Ann}(f^{\infty}):=\bigcup_{n\geq 1}\operatorname{Ann}(f^n)$ (this is an ideal as it is an increasing union). Then
$$
\overline{D(f)}=V(\operatorname{Ann}(f^{\infty}))=\bigcap_{n\geq 1}\operatorname{supp}((f^n)).
$$
Note also that if $A$ is reduced, then $\operatorname{Ann}(f^{\infty})=\operatorname{Ann}(f)$, because if $xf^n=0$ for some $n>0$ then $(xf)^n=0$ and hence $xf=0$. So in this case we *do* have $\overline{D(f)}=V(\operatorname{Ann}(f))$.

Comment: thank you @imtrying46 , I can't understand why $\operatorname{supp}(f)=D(f)
$ is open , it should be closed correct ? I have proved it in Vakil's Exercise 2.7.G. (THE SUPPORT OF A SECTION IS CLOSED).

Comment: @yili The definition of support in the question you are asking is that $\operatorname{supp}(s)=\{x\in X\mid s_x\neq 0\}$. So it corresponds to $\operatorname{supp}((f))$ in your post, which is indeed closed. On the other hand, $\operatorname{supp}(f)=\{p\in\operatorname{Spec}A\mid f(p)\neq 0\}$ is the non-vanishing locus of $f$, so also intuitively it should be open.

Comment: Thank you, clear now, when we say the support of function on a scheme $\text{Spec} A$ we should interpret it as support of section correct？

Comment: @yili Yes I think so, but it may depend on context.

Comment: Yeah, thank you imtrying46, the reduce case also shown in the exercise 5.5 C in Vakil's FOAG